# Как запретить скролл Яндекс.Карты, созданной через map-constructor

Tags: вёрстка, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-embed

Прошу совета, как запретить скролл карты.

Карта на странице высотой 600px ширина 100%. На устройствах с экраном меньше 600 карта занимает весь экран и дальнейший скролл страницы невозможен.

Карта создавалась при помощи map-constructor, раньше такие проблемы решались `scroll=false`, но сейчас он не срабатывает и скролл остается. Уменьшать размер карты нельзя. Думал наложить блок на мобильных устройствах поверх карты, но клиенту нужен функционал карт.

Answer (score 1):

При получении кода карты в виде JavaScript параметр `scroll=false` работает. Вы можете убедиться на примере ниже.

Для кода карты в iframe параметр недоступен.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A053bd947d462cc1a45aeba4070defff75501905071c0eaf68436ac9976ec698c&amp;width=500&amp;height=351&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=false"></script>
```

Comment: Сделал тестовую страницу с вашим кодом. http://glebkema.ru/work7s/yandex-map-test/ У меня при таче по карте прокручивается карта, а не страница. Если такая карта займёт всю видимую область экрана, к текстам после неё уже не добраться...

Comment: scroll=false отключает только масштабирование карты колесом мыши, тачевые поведения так не отключаются

Comment: Но вопрос, если правильно понял, про скролл на маленьких экранах.

Comment: Тачевые поведения в картах Конструктора отключить нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Как запретить скролл, не знаю.

В своих проектах подключаю две Яндекс.карты: статическую показываю на мобильных, а интерактивную — на широких экранах.

Отличие от накрывания карты блоком в том, что статическая карта по клику открывает страницу с полнофункциональной Яндекс.картой. А чтобы статическая карта адаптировалась к ширине экрана, располагаю её фоном и центрирую стилями.

Возможно, такое решение устроит вашего клиента.

Пример: http://glebkema.ru/tasks/double-yandex-map/  •  [CodePen](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/GxGRNX)

```css
@media (max-width: 767.99999999px) {
  .contacts-map > a {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/808225/208926">Double Yandex map</a></h1>
    <p>Uses two versions of the Yandex map: a static map for mobile, and an interactive one for the desktop.</p>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="section-map">
  <div class="contacts-map hidden-xs">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3Aea955533757d471b2800d252edb82f21c0258833676ef2921af2199f54b6bb08&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=400&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>
  </div>
  <div class="contacts-map visible-xs">
    <a href="https://yandex.ru/maps/?um=constructor%3Aea955533757d471b2800d252edb82f21c0258833676ef2921af2199f54b6bb08&amp;source=constructorStatic" target="_blank" style="background-image: url(https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/static/?um=constructor%3Aea955533757d471b2800d252edb82f21c0258833676ef2921af2199f54b6bb08&amp;width=600&amp;height=400&amp;lang=ru_RU"></a>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section-lorem">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, quo, asperiores, ea, officia soluta sed voluptate esse earum possimus ad aliquid non aut assumenda quibusdam illum perspiciatis hic. Qui, repudiandae.</p>
    <p>Non, omnis, labore, sint, quasi veniam facere magnam unde doloremque earum error nemo autem cum quibusdam illo numquam in possimus animi maiores voluptas ut! Eum quas distinctio eligendi fugit accusantium?</p>
    <p>Velit, provident, qui eveniet ea officia voluptates fugit mollitia repudiandae molestiae dolore quo dolor doloremque illo nemo quasi adipisci explicabo earum tempora. Saepe iure harum blanditiis excepturi neque natus eos!</p>
    <p>Cumque, at, aperiam esse facilis distinctio vero quos officiis nisi doloribus voluptatibus nesciunt repellendus tempora doloremque provident beatae molestias ipsum modi placeat iure eum delectus nulla eligendi temporibus? Excepturi, odit.</p>
    <p>Debitis, et iste hic quae id amet aspernatur molestias iusto vel quasi. Dolorum, maiores, tenetur, nisi voluptatum facilis laudantium atque dolor quia totam obcaecati exercitationem minima laboriosam explicabo doloremque sapiente!</p>
    <p>Odit, excepturi quo voluptatibus consectetur eos dicta aliquam dolorum officiis itaque iste distinctio obcaecati ratione deleniti odio voluptates totam temporibus possimus animi nostrum eveniet? Debitis consectetur accusantium repudiandae modi at!</p>
    <p>Dicta, repudiandae, aliquid quo ad nesciunt aperiam ut laboriosam non rerum blanditiis dolor commodi inventore veniam? Non, rem nostrum tempora sed cum repellendus impedit earum porro iure laboriosam quidem reiciendis!</p>
  </div>
</section>
```